# Assigning an array to another array - xcode/objective c

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I have a piece of code wherein I take an array retrieved from a table and assign it to another string array. However the string array returns back null.

Here is the code:

```
   NSArray *CalorieSet = [ActiveCaloriesDatabase database].ArrayofActivities;
       for (ActiveCalories *info in CalorieSet) {
       NSLog(@"in app delegate");
       NSLog(@"%d: %@, %@", info.uniqueId, info.activity, info.calories);
       [_pickData addObject:info.activity];
       NSLog(@"array in the for loop %@", CalorieSet);
}

       NSLog(@"count here is %d", _pickData.count);
```

Comment: Does the {NSLog(@"%d: %@, %@", info.uniqueId, info.activity, info.calories);} line print out correctly? Once for each element in the original array?

Comment: It does - everything except the assigned array is correct.

Comment: Ok. Does the final line print out as 'count here is 0'?

Comment: `NSMutableArray *_pickData = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];` check if you have written this statement! Seems that `_pickData` is your strings array that sends you nil

Comment: Did you `alloc` your array ?

Comment: yes to both - pickData was allocated and initialized earlier -

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pickData; in the header and the synthesize property in the imp file...

Comment: Again, just to check, does the final line print out as 'count here is 0'?